# CIVICRM respecte t'il la RGPD?

Tags: civicrm-home

Le règlement no 2016/679, dit règlement général sur la protection des données (RGPD, ou GDPR, de l'anglais General Data Protection Regulation) est applicable en France depuis le 25 Mai 2018 (normalement).

Nous avons des clients qui nous demandent la confirmation que CIVICRM respecte les règles de la RGPD.

1) Savez vous si c'est OK ou pas pour CIVICRM ?

2) Y a t'il un document qui en parle ?

Merci pour votre aide

Bonne journée

bien cordialement

Pierre COCHAT
Makoa

---

English translation:

Regulation No. 2016/679, known as the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR, or GDPR, from the English General Data Protection Regulation) has been applicable in France since May 25, 2018 (normally).

We have customers who ask us for confirmation that CIVICRM respects the rules of the GDPR.

1) Do you know if it's OK or not for CIVICRM?

2) Is there a document that talks about it?

Thanks for your help

Have a good day

Best regards

Pierre COCHAT Makoa

Answer (score 7):

Bienvenue sur Stack Exchange, avez-vous vérifié l'extension GDPR qui permet à vos bases de données CiviCRM de suivre les directives GDPR?

Vous pouvez l'installer via la page CiviCRM Extension Manager ou via ce lien - https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr

---

Welcome to Stack Exchange, have you checked out the GDPR extension which enables your CiviCRM databases to follow GDPR guidelines?

You can install this through the CiviCRM Extension Manager page or through this link - https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr

Comment: +2 for offering answer in Fr and En

Comment: I figured it would be the most useful, I also added the English translation to the question but it has yet to be approved!

Answer (score 4):

Jade's answer is very helpful, but I think its important to point out that a piece of software cannot be compliant or not to the regulation and that Pierre's users are actually asking the wrong question. Its your organisation's procedures and processes that are compliant with GDPR (RGPD) or not. The extension helps with that of course.

Hope that the Google translation is adequate as its the best I can do.

---

La réponse de Jade est très utile, mais je pense qu'il est important de souligner qu'un logiciel ne peut pas être conforme ou non à la réglementation et que les utilisateurs de Pierre posent en fait la mauvaise question. Il s'agit des procédures et processus de votre organisation conformes ou non au RGPD (GDPR). L'extension aide à cela bien sûr.

J'espère que la traduction de Google est adéquate car c'est la meilleure que je puisse faire.

Comment: +1 great addition!